# Rails Production: Premature end of script headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I'm attempting to host my rails app on a vps.  The issue that I'm running into is when I try to navigate to my rails app, I get the following error message:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

When I check out the virtual server's error log it tells me the following:

```
Premature end of script headers:
```

And sometimes that's followed with a `feed` or a `contact` or a `referer: myurl.com/` or nothing at all.

I've seen plenty of posts regarding this error messages elsewhere but none so far have resolved the matter. The general consensus seems to be that it likely has to do with the rails environment variable or file.

As this is my first attempt at putting a rails app on a production server, I figure this is plausible.  Below is my `environment.rb`

```
cat config/environment.rb 
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

As for the server, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Webmin/Virtualmin and apache2 with passenger.  Ruby 2.1.5p273 was installed using RVM and all gems are up to date.

Any thoughts would be helpful!

Comment: Is there anything in the production.log? It may have a backtrace that would give a little more information. Is the DB set up and created and all migrations run? That sometimes can cause problems in production. Or, check the apache logs (main error log, and the logs for your app).

Comment: @BillTurner Thanks for the response!  Your intuition proved helpful, though the log I needed to look at was my `/var/log/apache2/error.log`  There I found `from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `validate_secret_key_config!'`  I'm guessing I need to generate the secret key for SECRET_KEY_BASE.  Feel free to drop me a comment if you have any tips on best practices for that.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I was confronted with exactly the same problem. In my case it was the line 'secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>' in config/secrets.yml (but the env variable was not defined on the server). Please, look in §3.3 of http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response!  I think you're quite right, as I found some info in my error log consistent with your answer.  I found my secrets.yml file filled already filled out as your suggested documentation advised, including the line:`secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>`  I do not, however have the `secret_token.rb`; this is probably why the env variable was not defined.  How one should generate and manage this seems to be a bit vague.  Do you have any recommendations?  Many thanks again!

Comment: Update: I used `rake secret` to generate a new key and pasted it directly into secrets.yml, as [suggested here](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/downloaded-project-files-bundled-gems-but-having-trouble-with-secretyml-file-for-odot-app).  That worked well for getting rid of the key error in `/var/logs/apache2/error.log` but I'm still up against a 403 Forbidden error on my page.  Anything I might be leaving out?

Comment: Hi neanderslob, I also used 'rake secret' and pasted it directly into secrets.yml -- and it works for me (without 403 error). But I'm not happy about this, because I have not used the recommended way via ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"].

Comment: I have a hunch that my users are off.  Which user did you install ruby for?  Was it the apache www-data by any chance?